# Emit messages to client while a long-running method is in execution

Tags: javascript, meteor

Say I have a meteor method like this (just as a quick, workable example)

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
Meteor.methods({
  'wait': async function () {
    let i = 0;
    let timer;
    let interval;
    const emitter = new EventEmitter();

    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      timer = Meteor.setTimeout(resolve, 60 * 1000);

      // whenever this interval runs, inform the client running this.
      interval = Meteor.setInterval(() => {
        i++;
        i%2 === 0 ? emitter.emit('tick') : emitter.emit('tock');
      }, 500);
    }).finally(() => {
      Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
      Meteor.clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
  }
});
```

So on my client, I want to subscribe to this *while the method is in execution*. Eg, something like:

```
const asyncOperation = new Meteor.callEmitter('wait', function () {
  console.log('Oh look, your operation is complete.')
}).on('tick', () => {
  console.log('received tick'));
}).on('tock', () => {
  console.log('received tock')
});
```

Would this be possible to do in Meteor?

Comment: you mean something like setInterval, and check the state of your meteor methods in each iteration, being able to display messages on each iteration? [Window setInterval() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: this method is a pretty basic runnable example, but the use case is basically that I need to send messages to the client during the meteor method's execution so that it can display the current state. An example is connecting to a `net.Socket`, and streaming the results until reaching a particular message

Comment: I presume you want to avoid using a collection to communicate this data?

Comment: yeah that's ultimately the goal